# Is there way to delete all files and commits on github

Tags: git

I want to delete all files and commits on my github repository. But I don't want to destroy the repo. Stars should be stay. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being in the project's directory:

```
rm -rf .git/
git rm -r *
git init
git add .
git remote add origin projects_url
git commit -m "Remove everything"
git push -u --force origin master
```

Comment: I got this error "fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Comment: i fixed this by adding remote origin but files are not deleted in my repo

Comment: @JayGatsby oh right, I did not notice about the files, do the following: `git rm -r *` after the first line

Comment: You might need to check for other dot-files after the `rm` and remove them, too.

Answer (score 0):

Push an empty local repo with the `--mirror` flag

```
$ mkdir practice; cd practice;
$ git init; git remote add origin git@github.com:user/practice.git;

$ git push origin --mirror
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To git@github.com:user/practice.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:user/practice.git'
```

On GitHub you can get around this by making an initial commit then pushing.